# udp sendto lasting too long (unusual times)

Tags: linux, udp

In my application I'm sending data via an UDP socket with a rate of around 58MB/second. Most of the times it works fine however some time the sendto last too long and the time are grouped around 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 seconds (see immage below).
My system is a linux system with kernel 2.6.32-24-server, the buffer for each send is 45000 bytes long. Do you have a clue on why sometime this happens?

[image]

Comment: have you tried it with an RT kernel?

Answer (score 1):

From send(2):
`When  the  message  does  not  fit  into the send buffer of the socket,
     send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in  nonblock‐
     ing  I/O mode.  In nonblocking mode it would fail with the error EAGAIN
     or EWOULDBLOCK in this case.  The select(2) call may be used to  deter‐
     mine when it is possible to send more data.`

Other than this the kernel might be doing something else in the meantime. If this is the case, using an RT kernel might help as suggested by yi_H.

Comment: What is strange to me is why the 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and so on

Comment: Also a tenth second is a terrible long time for networking... how do you send the data? Is it sent evenly or in bursts? Could the send buffer get full? 100Mb/1Gb/.. card?

Comment: It's evenly, we have 1Gb card, we have upgraded to 2.6.38-10 that is thick less (the previous one 2.6.32-24 was not) and now we are not able to replicate the problem.